# Stored procedure performance is really slow

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a SQL Server stored procedure containing a whole batch of queries that used to be really quick on an old server, but is now really really slow on a newer server. I am trying to understand what is going wrong.

It is still in the middle of running a very long set of instructions, and I have run some queries to find out where the bottlenecks are.

It is coming up with the following stats:

[image: Stored procedure performance 1]

I ran a different query and it provided similar results:

[image: Stored procedure performance 2]

But what does all this mean? Any idea what I do next?

Edit: Just reading this article: https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/io-subsystem/knee-jerk-waits-pageiolatch-sh and it suggests that the CXPACKET type is being caused by parallel table scans, and the PACKETIOLATCH_SH is due to an IO subsystem (disk or network) problem. Still investigating.

Comment: You might be better off posting on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have?

Comment: Try this: In SQL Server Management Studio, right click the server > properties > Advanced Properties > change Cost Threshold for Parallelism to 120. Run the proc again and let me know if that helped with the speed. Also, how many processors do you have?

Comment: Very first thing to try is add OPTION RECOMPILE. This will give you an idea of whether the issue is parameter sniffing. If it improves it you can do some more thorough investigation https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robinlester/2016/08/10/improving-query-performance-with-option-recompile-constant-folding-and-avoiding-parameter-sniffing-issues/

Comment: The version is SQL Server 2014 (12.0.5000.0). The machine is 4 core (8 logical) processors. I have alterest the cost threshold for parallelism. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @tone would love to know if query performance has improved any. Also, was the old server a different version of SQL Server? You might also want to update your server to latest SP3/CU3, if you can. Also ensure that the database the proc is running on is set to latest compatibility level, if you can.

Comment: The old version of SQL was 2012. The performance does not appear to have improved.

Comment: Try something like this. Take out the query from the proc and run it separately. Does it run quickly? Is it that the query is running quickly, but when you put in a proc its slow, on the new server?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2014, there is a new query optimizer. It might be the reason why your SP performs badly. 
Try SP execution after setting database compatibility level 110.

```
ALTER DATABASE your_database SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL=110;
GO
```

Alternatively, I can change your SP by adding trace flag OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 9481)

Comment: Changing this can cause a lot of issues. SQL Functions  work on compatibility, if there are any other functions which are not compatible with 110, it will cause a serious trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems to me that there is already an issue. So, there is no bad idea to find out is that issue somehow connected with the query optimizer. It seems to me that it is. In that case user can leave trace flag or try to rewrite your SP.